# MVC 3 GlobalFilters Exclude

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a filter that would like to apply to all controllers except for one. So I am trying to write something that looks like this:

```
 public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
 {
     filters.Add(new MySweetAttribute()).Exclude(OneController);
 }
```

Trying to read through Brad's post on the subject is gibberish to me

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt4-filters.html

I am assuming it is possible since the library below seems to do it, but I would like to avoid adding a dependency if possible.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FluentFltrsASPNETMVC3.aspx

Hoping someone has done this already and it is easy to do...

Thanks for any help.

### Update

Phil Haack has just posted how to approach this scenario.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/25/conditional-filters.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to implement a filter provider to do this, then when you implement GetFilters do not apply the filter for the action you wish to exclude. Here is an example:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=578

Answer (score 32):

I've been searching the web for the same question without luck so I just tried this myself and it works:

```
public class MySweetAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public bool Disable { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Disable) return;

        ...
    }
}
```

Then, when you want to disable the global filter, just add the attribute to the action with the disable propierty set to true:

```
[MySweetAttribute(Disable=true)]
public ActionResult Index()
{            
    return View();
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Amazing and fast solution! :D

Comment: U R Z 1. Though, I have found many other answers, but this still  the simplest and most efficient answer all over the globe.

Comment: This is my preferred approach as well

Comment: One little "gotcha" I've noticed here - if you specify an Order in the global declaration of the filter, you must also specify the same order on on the attribute. Eg `[DataAccessAttribute(Disable=true,Order=2)]` and `filters.Add(new DataAccessAttribute(), 2);`

Answer (score 2):

You can't exclude from Global filters. If you want controllers to be excluded use standard filters.

Comment: Ok, so is there an easy to way to apply a filter to all but one controller? Readying through the new FilterProvider...

Comment: You could have all controllers that you want to have the filter applied to derive from a common base controller.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing IFilterProvider is not so complicated. See full sample which uses the provider facility to exclude a filter by type: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/oric/archive/2011/10/28/exclude-a-filter.aspx