# How to disable a global filter in ASP.Net MVC selectively

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionfilterattribute, global-filter

I have set up a global filter for all my controller actions in which I open and close NHibernate sessions. 95% of these action need some database access, but 5% don't. Is there any  easy way to disable this global filter for those 5%. I could go the other way round and decorate only the actions that need the database, but that would be far more work.

Comment: What about creating another action and decorate the 5% with this.  Something like NHibernateNotRequiredAttribute()?

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/new-filter-overrides-in-asp-net-mvc-5-and-asp-net-web-api-2

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You could write a marker attribute:

```
public class SkipMyGlobalActionFilterAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

and then in your global action filter test for the presence of this marker on the action:

```
public class MyGlobalActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SkipMyGlobalActionFilterAttribute), false).Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        // here do whatever you were intending to do
    }
}
```

and then if you want to exclude some action from the global filter simply decorate it with the marker attribute:

```
[SkipMyGlobalActionFilter]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Really great solution. I wonder how I didn't think of this by myself. Thanks.

Comment: This was helpful thanks. Just to help future people, you can also put the same thing on a Controller, and use filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes to apply to all actions.

Comment: anyone after api solution the syntax is slightly different: actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<SkipMyGlobalActionFilter>().Any()

Comment: And if you also want to skip specific controller attribute then you should add || in the condition filterContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<SkipMyGlobalActionFilter>().Any()

Comment: like Leniel wrote, in ASP.NET Core, filterContext.ActionDescriptor doens't have the GetCustomAttributes method. How to do it in ASP.NET core?

Comment: You do it this way. `context.ActionDescriptor.GetType().GetCustomAttributes (typeof (SkipMyGlobalActionFilterAttribute)`

Comment: I couldn't use .Any().Instead, I replaced it with .Length > 0

Comment: this is how I did it in .net core: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48895659/1343595

Comment: You can use this for .net core.   
if (context.Filters.Any(x => 
x.GetType() == typeof(SkipMyGlobalActionFilterAttribute))) 
{ base.OnActionExecuted(context); return; }
Before you must change with 
SkipMyGlobalActionFilterAttribute :ActionFilterAttribute

Answer (score 16):

Though, the accepted answer by Darin Dimitrov is fine and working well but, for me, the simplest and most efficient answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5600583/1541152).

You just need to add a boolean property to your attribute and check against it, just before your logic begins:

```
public class DataAccessAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public bool Disable { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Disable) return;

        // Your original logic for your 95% actions goes here.
    }
}
```

Then at your 5% actions just use it like this:

```
[DataAccessAttribute(Disable=true)]
public ActionResult Index()
{            
    return View();
}
```

Comment: One little "gotcha" I've noticed here - if you specify an Order in the global declaration of the filter, you must also specify the same order on on the attribute. Eg `[DataAccessAttribute(Disable=true,Order=2)]` and `filters.Add(new DataAccessAttribute(), 2);`

Answer (score 9):

In AspNetCore, the accepted answer by @darin-dimitrov can be adapted to work as follows:

First, implement `IFilterMetadata` on the marker attribute:

```
public class SkipMyGlobalActionFilterAttribute : Attribute, IFilterMetadata
{
}
```

Then search the `Filters` property for this attribute on the `ActionExecutingContext`:

```
public class MyGlobalActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Filters.OfType<SkipMyGlobalActionFilterAttribute>().Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: So much cleaner. Works for attributes set on action as well as controller.

Answer (score 4):

At least nowadays, this is quite easy: to exclude all action filters from an action, just add the **OverrideActionFiltersAttribute**.

There are similar attributes for other filters: **OverrideAuthenticationAttribute**, **OverrideAuthorizationAttribute** and **OverrideExceptionAttribute**.

See also https://www.strathweb.com/2013/06/overriding-filters-in-asp-net-web-api-vnext/

Comment: Nowadays being 2013+? Not sure why this isn't the accepted answer as it seems canonical.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom Filter Provider. Write a class which will implement IFilterProvider. This IFilterProvider interface has a method GetFilters which returns Filters which needs to be executed.

```
public class MyFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
        private readonly List<Func<ControllerContext, object>> filterconditions = new List<Func<ControllerContext, object>>();
        public void Add(Func<ControllerContext, object> mycondition)
        {
            filterconditions.Add(mycondition);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
        {
            return from filtercondition in filterconditions
                   select filtercondition(controllerContext) into ctrlContext
                   where ctrlContext!= null
                   select new Filter(ctrlContext, FilterScope.Global);
        }
}
```

=============================================================================
In Global.asax.cs

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            MyFilterProvider provider = new MyFilterProvider();
            provider.Add(d => d.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() != "SkipFilterAction1 " ? new NHibernateActionFilter() : null);
            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(provider);
        }


protected void Application_Start()
{
    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think I got it working for ASP.NET Core.
Here's the code:

```
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        // Prepare the audit
        _parameters = context.ActionArguments;

        await next();

        if (IsExcluded(context))
        {
            return;
        }

        var routeData = context.RouteData;

        var controllerName = (string)routeData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string)routeData.Values["action"];

        // Log action data
        var auditEntry = new AuditEntry
        {
            ActionName = actionName,
            EntityType = controllerName,
            EntityID = GetEntityId(),
            PerformedAt = DateTime.Now,
            PersonID = context.HttpContext.Session.GetCurrentUser()?.PersonId.ToString()
        };

        _auditHandler.DbContext.Audits.Add(auditEntry);
        await _auditHandler.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private bool IsExcluded(ActionContext context)
    {
        var controllerActionDescriptor = (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptor)context.ActionDescriptor;

        return controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.IsDefined(typeof(ExcludeFromAuditing), false) ||
               controllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.IsDefined(typeof(ExcludeFromAuditing), false);
    }
```

The relevant code is in the 'IsExcluded' method.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your filter code like this:

```
 public class NHibernateActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> ActionsToSkip { get; set; }

        public NHibernateActionFilter(params string[] actionsToSkip)
        {
            ActionsToSkip = actionsToSkip;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (null != ActionsToSkip && ActionsToSkip.Any(a => 
String.Compare(a,  filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName, true) == 0))
                {
                    return;
                }
           //here you code
        }
    }
```

And use it:

```
[NHibernateActionFilter(new[] { "SkipFilterAction1 ", "Action2"})]
```

Comment: That's one way to do it, but a little difficult to maintain over time.

Comment: If you change your action name and forget to change it in the attribute usage, the compiler won't warn you. This is very likely to cause maintenance pains. I prefer Darin's answer since you don't have to specify the actions manually.