# How to use MembershipUser.IsApproved for account confirmation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

Here's what I want to achieve with ASP.Net MVC 3 :

Before a user can actively use my website, I want them to fill a form and give a few details. Unless they have done so, they get redirected to the form website.

I thought this would be feasible by registering the account with the IsApproved-flag set to false, but actually such users cannot login at all (`Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)` always returns false).

Is there any mechanism in forms authentication that supports this scenario? Or will I have to track this in a custom database table?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT : Thanks to MystereMan (read his reply first) and a few other great posts here on SO, here's the ActionFilter (Attribute and its usage):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class RedirectUserInRoleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public string TargetControllerName { get; set; }

    public string TargetActionName { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
        if (user != null)
        {
            string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(user.UserName);

            if (roles.Any(x => x == RoleName))
            {
                RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
                redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", TargetActionName);
                redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", TargetControllerName);

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);
            }
        }
    }
}


[Authorize]
[RedirectUserInRole(RoleName = "Pending", TargetControllerName = "Home", TargetActionName = "Index")]
public ActionResult ChangePassword()
{
  //...
}

[Authorize]
[RedirectUserInRole(RoleName = "Member", TargetControllerName = "Home", TargetActionName = "Index")]
public ActionResult Confirm()
{
  // show confirm form here!
}
```

Comment: Nice, and pretty generic as well.

Comment: One change, you may want to add it as a global action filter, rather than applying it to all your action methods and/or controllers.

Comment: how so? Sorry, pretty new to MVC ;)

Comment: You add it to the RegisterGlobalFilters in global.asax

Comment: Thanks! The Problem is, that this leads to an endless recursion when a pending user tries to open the form (Confirm Action). Can you make exceptions to global filters?

Comment: one way : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953760/how-to-disable-a-global-filter-in-asp-net-mvc-selectively

Comment: Well, that was what I warned about in my edit.  If you don't mind hard-coding it, you can just put checks in your filter and see if the current route is whatever route you want to exclude.  Another way is that you could pass a comma delimited list of routes to exclude and then parse that list in your filter and again compare it to the current route.  Or you can use the attribute method you mention.

Comment: Again thanks, that was all pretty awesome!

Comment: MVC is all about choices and options.  There are usually 2 or 3 or more different ways to do something.  That can be confusing, but it gives you lots of flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to create a "Pending" membership role.  When you first create the account, assign them to the "Pending" role.  Then, you can create a Action filter that will redirect all users in the Pending role to your form.

EDIT:

A few gotchas to watch out for:

- Make sure you reassign them to a different role after they've completed the form
- Make sure you don't redirect them on the form action itself, or it's post action (otherwise you will be in an infinite loop)
- You may want to prevent users in other roles from navigating to the form.

Comment: sounds like a great idea! I'll try that!

Comment: Thanks a lot, you put me in the right direction. I've updated the original Post with the solution.

Comment: thanks for your edit. Got that sorted out with the great filters =) cool concept, big props to the MVC guys!

Answer (score 0):

You have to track that information by yourself. You can create an own table as you suggested and link it to the aspnet_users table or add a column to the aspnet_users table.