# MVC avoid onexception for one method alone

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In mvc razor 4 application, we have written a custom error class CustomErrorHelper which inherits HandleErrorAttribute, and have the following method:

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            //exception handling    
        }
```

This exception handler class is registered in Gloabal.asax.cs using RegisterGlobalFilters method.

```
 public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new CustomErrorHelper());
        }
```

Now we have used this our controller, so for every method in the controller this exception handling is getting invoked for any exception. There is one specific method in the controller for which we dont want to override with this exception, we want to skip this onexception call in case any exception occurs in this method. How do we do this? Can we turn off this exception handling at method level?

Comment: maybe just wrap this method with `try\catch` block?

Comment: after executing catch block it goes to onexception. I want to prevent it from going to onexception.

Comment: if you don't rethrow exception in catch block, and just suppress exception, then it won't go to `OnException`. But you should remember, that exception suppressing isn't very good practice

Comment: Use a solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953760/how-to-disable-a-global-filter-in-asp-net-mvc-selectively

Comment: @Sergey Litvinov : even if i dont throw exception the onexception gets called, it gets called for any methods in the controller where exception occurs.

Comment: @haim770 : i did try the approach mentioned in the link but its not giving me expected behaviour, i just want to skip onexception for just method, isnt there any attibute to swich it off at methods level, even though it is being used at class level in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/oric/2011/10/28/exclude-a-filter/

I used the logic in this link to ignore the exception