# Prevent a ASP.NET MVC global filter from being applied on Elmah action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elmah, action-filter

I'm using Elmah for logging exceptions on my MVC application using [Alex Beletsky's elmah-mvc](https://github.com/alexbeletsky/elmah-mvc) NuGet package.

The application registers some global filters, applied on each action called.

Is there a way to prevent some of those filters from being applied when calling the `Elmah.Mvc.ElmahController` error log page (`foo.com/elmah`) ?

A test like below works, of course, but I'm looking for a more elegant way that would not involve modifying the filter (nor the source code from Elmah / Elmah MVC). Is it even possible ?

```
public class FooAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    // ...

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Controller is ElmahController)
        {
            return;
        }

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

- I know that attributes [can't be added or removed at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/129285/1679537).
- I thought of wrapping the `ElmahController` in a new one where I could add an exclusion filter, but I'm not sure how (if possible) to change the `web.config` to reference this wrapper instead of the original controller.

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953760/how-to-disable-a-global-filter-in-asp-net-mvc-selectively

Comment: @malkam I know this one. The problem is that it involves decorating the action with an attribute, i.e. modifying Elmah source code, which I don't want to do, for obvious reasons.

Comment: this solution doesn't seem so terrible to me. I would probably do it in the positive though: `if(controller is ElmahController) { //return with no special actions`

Comment: @DLeh You're right, it's not so bad, I agree. I'm just looking to ways of achieving this without having to alter the filter itself, so that I don't have to alter each and every filter with ElmahController when I'll need to exclude them as well.

Comment: maybe you could make your filters extend a base filter that has this code in one spot?

Comment: @DLeh That's the same in the end. As soon as I'll need to exclude a filter, I'll have to make it extend this base class, i.e. modify it. Not mentioning filters already extending another class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could register your global filters through a custom [`IFilterProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ifilterprovider(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
public class MyFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        if (controllerContext.Controller is ElmahController)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<Filter>();
        }

        return ... the collection of your global filters
    }
}
```

and in your `Application_Start` instead of calling:

```
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

you would call:

```
FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new MyFilterProvider());
```

Comment: That's the idea. I'll have to get the internal Elmah.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute from the global filters (it gets automatically registered during app start http://beletsky.net/2012/06/elmahmvc-v200-release-candidate.html), but I guess this is the solution I'm looking for. Thanks!