# Use Request.IsAjaxRequest() Globally in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to block direct access of action method by web browser. However I want to invoke the actions through ajax call.

The following code does the job for me

```
public ActionResult DashBoard()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

However writing `if else` block in every action method is hectic thing to do and there must be  better way to handle it globally.

Comment: Create an action filter and apply it globally - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900411/mvc-set-accessibility-level-on-a-method-called-from-ajax/23900475#23900475) for an example (in that case it returns a 404 if not an ajax request

Comment: Thanks, I did implement it globally too. However I don't want the filter on on my home page. How do i exclude this filter in specific Action Method

Comment: In that case, consider a BaseController and apply the filter to that controller. Then have all your controllers except HomeController inherit from BaseController. Another option is to register your filters using a `IFilterProvider` (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193082/prevent-a-asp-net-mvc-global-filter-from-being-applied-on-elmah-action) for an example)

Comment: Thanks, It worked :)