# Using IOverrideFilter to override custom ActionFilters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use `IOverrideFilter` interface to override my custom global filter but it is simply not working! Code looks like to be as follow:

```
public sealed class MyGlobalFilterExceptionAttribute : FilterAttribute, IOverrideFilter
{
    public Type FiltersToOverride
    {
        get { return typeof(ITest); }
    }
}
```

My global filter has implemented `ITest` interface. I know I can implement the task in my original global filter but I would like to do so by `IOverrideFilter`.

Any Idea??

Answer (score 8):

The msdn info is not entirely clear about it but [`IOverrideFilter.FiltersToOverride`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filters.ioverridefilter.filterstooverride(v=vs.118).aspx) must be **exactly** one of the following:

- `IActionFilter`
- `IAuthorizationFilter`
- `IAuthenticationFilter`
- `IExceptionFilter`

Basically, you cannot override specific filters, you can only override all the filters of one of the categories above. Have a look a the `ProcessOverrideFilters` method in the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/FilterInfo.cs).

So, let's say that your `ITest` filter is of type `IActionFilter`, then your override will be (The same logic would apply for any other filter category):

```
public Type FiltersToOverride
{
    get { return typeof(IActionFilter); }
}
```

You could also use the predefined [`OverrideActionFilters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.overrideactionfiltersattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) (and similar predefined override attributes for other filter categories).

For a more fine-grained override, you might need to develop specific solutions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953760/how-to-disable-a-global-filter-in-asp-net-mvc-selectively) or write your own filter provider [as in this very nice article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/oric/2011/10/28/exclude-a-filter/)