# Combine custom AuthorizeAttribute and RequireHttpsAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a custom `RequireHttpsAttribute` and a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` that I apply in `FilterConfig` to ensure that all controllers uses HTTPS and authorizes in the same way.

I also have a controller action that need some other authorization. In that case I must first use `[OverrideAuthorization]` to override the global authorization filter, and then I can set the special authorization for this action.

But `[OverrideAuthorization]` will also override the `CustomRequireHttpsAttribute` since that also inherts from `IAuthorizationFilter`. What can I do so that I don't have to readd the `CustomRequireHttpsAttribute` attribute every time I override the authorization?

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new CustomRequireHttpsAttribute());
        filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeAttribute(Role = "User"));
    }
}

public class MyController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult DoSomeUserStuff()
    {
    }

    [OverrideAuthorization]
    [CustomRequireHttpsAttribute]
    [CustomAuthorizeAttribute(Role = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult DoSomeAdminStuff()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712977/using-ioverridefilter-to-override-custom-actionfilters seems like it could be worth looking at. Not a duplicate but the solutions there might be a different way of you solving your problem. Other options would be to have multiple base controllers, one for admin and one for user and decorate the base class with your filter attributes. All of these possibilities are ways to solve the problem differently rather than directly answering what you've asked which is why I'm commenting and not answering.

Comment: @Chris thank you for your input, but like you say, none of those are really the solution that I'm looking for. However, I did end up using one of the methods mentioned in the post you linked, a custom FilterProvider.

Comment: I thought that looked like it was probably the one that most suited what you were after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating my own custom `IFilterProvider` based on a modified version of [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/oric/2011/10/28/exclude-a-filter/) post.

I added an extra attribute that I can use for those Controllers or Actions where I want to override the attribute that is set globally. It really does nothing else than extend `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` so that it carries the same functionality:

```
public class OverrideCustomAuthorizeAttribute : CustomAuthorizeAttribute {}
```

Then I create an `IFilterProvider` that checks the presence of any `OverrideCustomAuthorizeAttribute`s in the list of filters. If so, remove all `CustomAuthorizeAttribute`s from the list:

```
public class CustomFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    private readonly FilterProviderCollection _filterProviders;

    public CustomFilterProvider(IList<IFilterProvider> filters)
    {
        _filterProviders = new FilterProviderCollection(filters);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        var filters = _filterProviders.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor).ToArray();

        var shouldOverrideCustomAuthorizeAttribute = filters.Any(filter => filter.Instance is OverrideCustomAuthorizeAttribute);
        if (shouldOverrideCustomAuthorizeAttribute)
        {
            // There is an OverrideCustomAuthorizeFilterAttribute present, remove all CustomAuthorizeAttributes from the list of filters
            return filters.Where(filter => filter.Instance.GetType() != typeof(CustomAuthorizeAttribute));
        }

        return filters;
    }
}
```

I register this `IFilterProvider` in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // Some other stuff first....

        var providers = FilterProviders.Providers.ToArray();
        FilterProviders.Providers.Clear();
        FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new CustomFilterProvider(providers));
    }
}
```

And I register the global `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` in `FilterConfig.cs` just like before:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new CustomRequireHttpsAttribute());
        filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeAttribute(Role = "User"));
    }
}
```

The difference is that I use `OverrideCustomAuthorizeAttribute` in the controller instead:

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult DoSomeUserStuff()
    {
    }

    [OverrideCustomAuthorizeAttribute(Role = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult DoSomeAdminStuff()
    {
    }
}
```

This way, `CustomRequireHttpsAttribute` is always set globally and never overridden.

Comment: That makes some really neat code in the end. And looked pretty simple to implement (once you knew what you needed, of course). Glad you got it working. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://forums.asp.net/t/1938635.aspx?How+to+use+Filter+overrides+in+the+ASP+NET+MVC+5+), you can specify which filters to override in the [`OverrideAuthorizationAttribute.FiltersToOverride` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.overrideauthorizationattribute.filterstooverride(v=vs.118).aspx).

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult DoSomeUserStuff()
    {
    }

    [OverrideAuthorization(FiltersToOverride = typeof(CustomAuthorizeAttribute))]
    [CustomAuthorizeAttribute(Role = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult DoSomeAdminStuff()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I tried this and it will not work. `FiltersToOverride` must be exactly of one of the types IActionFilter, IAuthorizationFilter, IAuthenticationFilter, IExceptionFilter (check here: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/FilterInfo.cs). Both `RequireHttpsAttribute` and `AuthorizeAttribute` that my custom attributes derive from are of type `IAuthorizationFilter`