# How to Disable Actionfilter for only one method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created one action filter called [ValidateUrlAttribute], I want to use this action filter except some methods in my class.I tried this following thing but its not working

```
  public class ActionExemptionsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
    public string Exemption { get; set; }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action") == Exemption)
            return;

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

 }
```

Comment: mind sharing some of codes ? And anything you tried which didn't work ?

Comment: I think you can find what you need in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953760/how-to-disable-a-global-filter-in-asp-net-mvc-selectively

Comment: [ActionExemptions(Exemption= "GetUserDetailsForCreatePassword")] in controller i tried like this but its not working

Comment: If you apply two action filters to a method/controller, both will be executed.  The code above does nothing either way because either it explicitly does nothing (when the exemption matches) or implicitly does nothing (because the base ActionFilterAttribute does nothing).  If you want to control the behavior of another action filter, the one you are trying to control needs to be aware of your new attribute.  The method Charmander linked to or the one Jacek posted is what needs to be added to your ValidateUrlAttribute action filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should introduce custom attribute (for example SkipActionExemptionsAttribute), which you use to decarate action where you want to skip check url

In your ActionExemptionsAttribute check if action is decorated with Skip attribute.

```
 actionContext
       .ActionDescriptor
       .GetCustomAttributes<SkipActionExemptionsAttribute>()
       .Any()
```