# Restrict action filter attribute for one action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionfilterattribute

I have implemented Action filter attribute and have declared Globally using Global.asax.cs file.

For Example if I have created XYZ action filter attribute and in Global.asax.cs file declared like below:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new XYZ());
```

Using above code it applies to all action methods. Now I do not want this filter attribute for one method say ABC. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to this question[1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953760/how-to-disable-a-global-filter-in-asp-net-mvc-selectively

Comment: @tynar: Thank you for your response. I will try this solution and let you know.