# Web Api filters - Check if decorator is present

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

There are plenty of samples on how to check if a decorator is present on an ASP.NET MVC action. (e.g [How to disable a global filter in ASP.Net MVC selectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953760/how-to-disable-a-global-filter-in-asp-net-mvc-selectively))

How can I accomplish the same on a Web Api endpoint ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the following Attributes:

```
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

public class CustomAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // Does the action have the AnotherCustomAttribute attribute on it?
        if (Enumerable.Any<AnotherCustomAttribute>((IEnumerable<AnotherCustomAttribute>)actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AnotherCustomAttribute>()))
        {
            // WebAPI action has your AnotherCustomAttribute attribute on it
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}

public class AnotherCustomAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

You can check the presence of one using the other:

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    public HomeController()
    {
    }

    [CustomAttribute] // Checks for presence of 'AnotherCustomAttribute'
    [AnotherCustomAttribute]
    public object Get(int id)
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

NB: This uses `ActionFilterAttribute` from the `System.Web.Http.Filters` namespace and not `System.Web.Mvc`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just found out how to do it:

```
public class ValidateSomethingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {

        var isIgnorePresent = ((ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor)actionContext.ActionDescriptor).MethodInfo
                                                                                                   .CustomAttributes
                                                                                                   .Any(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(IgnoreValidateSomethingAttribute));
        if (isIgnorePresent) return;
```

Comment: Your code will work only if `ActionDescriptor` is `ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor` (i.e. no custom action descriptor provider was used) and only for action filters.