# Using AttributeAuthorization For Global Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have register a global filter to authorize requests that need a cookie but I have a controller that needs to be public so I add [AllowAnonymous] attribute to the controller methods but my filter still fires and keeps redirecting.  I'm not sure the best way to fix this issue.

Do I need to modify my onauthorization method to look for the [AllowAnonymous] attribute?

```
  public class CookieAuthFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
        {
            public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
            {
                HttpCookie cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("token");
                if (cookie == null)
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Home/Index");
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953760/how-to-disable-a-global-filter-in-asp-net-mvc-selectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to modify my onauthorization method to look for the [AllowAnonymous] attribute?

You could, but it would be simpler just to move your logic so the base `OnAuthorize` method (which contains the [logic to scan for `[AllowAnonymous]`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L94-L95)) is unmodified.

```
public class CookieAuthFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return httpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("token") != null;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Home/Index");
    }
}
```

It is better to use `AuthorizeCore` to return true if the user is authorized, and use `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` for the redirect.

`OnAuthorization` also contains some [additional logic to help it deal with output caching](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L104-L114) that you should leave in place.

Comment: Thanks so much for that.  Works perfectly.