# Get custom attributes via ActionExecutingContext from controller .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

This used used to work with earlier version of .Net. What's the equivalent in .net core terms. Now I get following error:

'ActionDescriptor' does not contain a definition for '**GetCustomAttributes**' and no extension method '**GetCustomAttributes**' accepting a first argument of type 'ActionDescriptor' could be found

```
public virtual void SetupMetadata(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var myAttr = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false);
    if (myAttr.Length == 1)
        //do something
}
```

Attribute definition:

```
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string _parameter;

    public PageTitleAttribute(string parameter)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
    }

    public string Parameter { get { return _parameter; } }
}
```

Code Usage:

```
[MyAttribute("Attribute value is set here")]
public ActionResult About()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Hope to help others, here's what i did:

```
var attrib = (filterContext.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor).MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes<MyAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: For those looking to do the same for a parameter: cast a `ControllerActionDescriptor.Parameters` to `ControllerParameterDescriptor` which has a `ParameterInfo` for all the usual reflection information.

Answer (score 15):

Another option without needing a runtime cast:

```
public class MyAttribute :  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute {
  // same content as in the question
}
```

By inheriting from `ActionFilterAttribute`, your attribute will now appear in the [ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions.actiondescriptor.filterdescriptors?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Abstractions_ActionDescriptor_FilterDescriptors) collection, and you can search that:

```
public virtual void SetupMetadata(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var myAttr = filterContext.ActionDescriptor
        .FilterDescriptors
        .Where(x => x.Filter is MyAttribute)
        .ToArray();
    if (myAttr.Length == 1) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I'm unsure if this is dirtier or cleaner than casting to `ControllerActionDescriptor`, but it's an option if you control the attribute.

Comment: A more direct way could be

`bool isAttributeSet = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors.Any(fd => fd.Filter is MyAttribute);`

Answer (score 8):

For ASP.NET Core 3+:

```cs
    var filters = context.Filters;
    // And filter it like this: 
    var filtered = filters.OfType<OurFilterType>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use:

```
filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false).Any()
```

Comment: This just gets controller's attributes not action's attributes.