# How can I define a custom attribute in ASP.NET Core Web API for endpoints and return an ObjectResult in it?

Tags: asp.net-core, attributes, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating an ASP.NET Core Web API project. I want to define an attribute (for example `ExampleAttribute`) and access the `HttpContext` in it and doing some action and finally return an `ObjectResult` if necessary, or continue.

I don't know if I am doing it right or not, but I want to define an attribute in this way:

```
public class DeveloperTaskAttribute : Attribute
{
    // using HttpContext and doing some action

    // I will returning BadRequest("") if necessary
    // or continue...
}
```

And I'm trying to use this attribute on this endpoint:

```
[HttpGet]
[ExampleAttribute] // using attribute
public IActionResult EndPoint1() 
{      
    // doing some action in endpoint1
}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ActionFilterAttribute Only:

Defining a new Attribute:

```
public class TestAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public TestAttribute() : base(typeof(TestFilter))
        {
        }

        private class TestFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            private readonly MyDbContext _myDbContext;

            public TestFilter(MyDbContext myDbContext)
            {
                _myDbContext = myDbContext;
            }

            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
            {
                // Dont use async - await methods !
                // Do something
                var user= context.HttpContext.User    
            }
        }


    }
```

Note: You must use the word ***Attribute*** at the end of the name

And using in controller:

```
    [Test]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Example")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExampleMethod()
    {}
```

Documentation: https://www.andybutland.dev/2020/06/dependency-injection-in-aspnet-core-attributes.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using attribute, use ActionFilter and Attribute.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

[Get custom attributes via ActionExecutingContext from controller .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803449/get-custom-attributes-via-actionexecutingcontext-from-controller-net-core)

First define an attribute :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class SampleAttribute : Attribute
{ 
}
```

Then define a class which is implement IActionFilter :

```
public sealed class SampleActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context){ }
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var attrib = (context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor).MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes<SampleAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (attrib is null) return;

        if (!someCondition) return;

        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        context.Result = new ObjectResult(new { done = false });
    }
}
```

To register this action filter :

```
services.AddControllers(mvcOptions => { mvcOptions.Filters.Add<SampleActionFilter>(); });
```