# Avoid OnResultExecuted Filter on ASP.NET MVC 5 application's Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, action-filter

I'm working on an MVC5 application that has a OnResultExecuted filter that sets the response cache to always "no-cache no-store":

```
public class NoCacheActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{       
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpCachePolicyBase cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        cache.SetExpires(now.AddDays(-1));
        cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

But i have one Action that needs to cache its result, so i set the OutputCahce atribute on it.

```
[OutputCache(Duration =300, Location =System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Client)]
```

But, because of the filter, it is never cached.

My question is if is there a way to avoid the filter for that action only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since the answer to this question was deleted... and i don't know why... I'm going to post the solution that worked for me. I leave the answer because i think it is interesting to know that there is another way to avoid default global filters than implementing "dumb" attributes like in the perfectly valid solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953760/how-to-disable-a-global-filter-in-asp-net-mvc-selectively).

First: This solution is only valid because the OutputCacheAttribute has "AllowMultiple" set to false, so it is OK to replace the NoCacheActionFilter and just add the OutputCacheAttribute at Global Filters like

```
filters.Add(new OutputCacheAttribute { Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*" });
```

And then if i add a OutputCacheAttribute at Action level, it will replace the Global default OutputCache filter configured before (because it has AllowMultiple set to false).

```
[OutputCache(Duration =300, VaryByParam = "param")]
public FileContentResult WhateverWithCache(string param)
{}
```

**Side note:**

The "AllowMultiple" property in OutputCacheAttribute is a property that can be defined in any attribute implemented in C#, and tells the attribute if it can be set more than once for a single element. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes)